# Slash transforms in %2F in router-link params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to pass a link to the parameters, but instead of a slash I get `%2F` in the link

My route

```js
{
    path: 'folder/:name+',
    name: 'folder',

    component: () => import("./components/FolderComponent.vue"),
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        console.log(to)
        var path = '';
        if (Array.isArray(to.params.name)) {
            path = to.params.name.join('/');
        } else {
            path = to.params.name;
        }
        axios.get('/api/file/folder/' + path).then(r => {
            store.commit('set_folder', r.data.data[0]);
            next();
        })

    }
}
```

router-link

```
 <router-link :to="{name: 'folder', params: {name: folder.path}}" class="file-preview">
```

href link
[href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55kQL.png)

Comment: %2F is because the link is getting encoded. You'll need to decode it at the other end.